# Can somebody help me to solve this equation? probability

Tags: probability

Suppose that the amount of time that a battery functions is a normal random variable with a mean of 400 hours and a standard deviation of 50 hours. If two batteries are randomly picked with the intention of using one as a spare to replace the other if it fails,  what is the probability that the longer-lasting battery will outlive the other by at least 25 hours?

I've made an equation but don't know how to solve it.

Pr{max{x1, x2}-min{x1,x2}>25} = ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can consider the distribution of the  difference $\Delta t$ between the lifetimes of both batteries. This is, again, a normal distribution $\Delta t \sim N(\mu,\sigma)$ but with mean $\mu=0$ and a standart deviation of $\sigma =\sqrt{2}\cdot 50$. You then need to compute the probability

$$p(|\Delta t| \geq 25) = 2\cdot\Phi_{0,\sqrt{2}\cdot 50}(-25)\approx0.724$$

where $\Phi_{0,\sqrt{2}\cdot 50}$ is the cumulative distribution function of the normal distribution.

Comment: Thank you so much! When I'm trying to solve an equation like P(x1+x2>a)=? What I just did was P(x1+x2>a)=P(Z>a-μtotal/σtotal)=..(μtotal =  μ1+ μ2 , σ^2total = σ1^2+σ2^2) I look up the number of standard normal distribution table and get the answer. What I'm still curious about is, (|Δ|≥25)=2⋅Φ0,2√⋅50(−25). using phi(the cumulative distribution function) in this equation. Is it because we deal with the difference not the sum?

Comment: Looking up the probability of z-scores is also perfectly valid. I used $\Phi$ out of laziness. The z-score would be $z = \frac{-25}{\sqrt{2}\cdot 50}$.